# Why not just assign value to target in method header.clone

Tags: go

the official version
my question is What's the role of "sv"

```golang
func (h Header) Clone() Header {
    if h == nil {
        return nil
    }

    // Find total number of values.
    nv := 0
    for _, vv := range h {
        nv += len(vv)
    }
    sv := make([]string, nv) // shared backing array for headers' values
    h2 := make(Header, len(h))
    for k, vv := range h {
        n := copy(sv, vv)
        h2[k] = sv[:n:n]
        sv = sv[n:]
    }
    return h2
}
```

Why not just write it like this
just assgin  value to h2 instead of creating a slice

```golang
    for k, vv := range h {
        // changed here
        h2[k] = vv
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `Header` is a `map[string][]string`, (maybe http.Header?). If it did what you suggested, then the new `Header` would be a shallow copy of the map, containing the original slices from the source `Header`. If the contents of the backing array of those slices are modified, the copied header would be modified as well. For instance:

```
s:=make([]string,0,10)
s=append(s,"a")
header[key]=s
h2:=header.Clone()
s=append(s,"b")
// Here, both header[key] and h2[key] has two elements, "a" and "b"
```

The prevent this, `Clone` is doing a deep copy, where each `[]string` is also copied. That would need `len(h)` string slice allocations, one for each key. Instead, this algorithm uses one allocation, a single shared string slice containing all the strings of the original header.

The algorithm first counts the number of strings contained in the header, and allocates a string slice of that size. In the second for loop, it copies the strings from the value of a key to the shared string slice, creates a slice using that shared slice array and sets it as the value of the key, and then updates the shared slice to point to the next available empty slot. In the end, it is a deep-copy with a single memory allocation instead of `len(h)`.

Comment: thank you very much!!! it really helps!!!!!!!!!!!  you are so kind!!! O(∩_∩)O